# How to install IBPlugin to Xcode4?

Tags: xcode4

How to install IBPlugin to Xcode4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/Xcode4/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Interface Builder/Plug-ins` ?

Comment: My plugin works for xcode 3. I copied it to the folder above but it doesn't load in xcode. Is there anything special I need to do?

Comment: XCode 4 does not support IBPlugins, as mentioned in the Release Notes.

Comment: yeah but it looks like some people got it to work (Kevin.lu said it worked above)

Comment: ...take a look at the most recent (NDA'd) betas. ;-)